# In what case would template template parameters be useful?

Tags: c++, c++14

I don't see a case where template template parameters would ever be useful, when they could be simply replaced with one template parameter that would work just as well. Referring to my example:

```
template<template<typename, typename...> typename Cont, typename T, typename... Args>
void Foo(Cont<T, Args...> container)
{
  for (auto i : container)
    std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void Bar(T container)
{
  for (auto i : container)
    std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

These will function identically, and `Bar` will work on any container defining an iterator (allocator not needed). `Foo` however, does the same thing, but is a lot more confusing to write (and more confusing to understand). I don't know if I missed the point on template template parameters, but they really seem useless to me as a single template parameter will deduce the type too, albeit without the other parameters.

Also - should I be using `typename` or `class` for the template template parameter?

`template<typename> class T`

or

`template<typename> typename T`

Comment: C++17 allows to use `typename` or `class` there.

Comment: An example of something which SHOULD have been a template template parameter is a standard allocator. It would normally be a template itself, instantiated with a specific element being allocated (which for many standard containers is not the data type). However, the lack of support for template template parameters was circumvented with a `rebind` member of a concrete type allocator.

Comment: When you want type, you might even use both method (template template parameters + its parameters vs type). But sometime you might really want only the `template template parameters` (`void foo(C<int>)` or `bar<std::vector>()`).